# Getting export declarations may only appear at top level of a module in JavaScript when exporting

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

No matter where I put the export statement I get the same error

> export declarations may only appear at top level of a module

I've tried adding type="module" to the script tag but it didn't help and I'm trying to avoid it.

**JS**:

```
export { LogTypes, DateTypes, GetTypes, get, show, hide } from ...;

const LogTypes = {
    Default: "DEFAULT",
    Info: "INFO",
    Warn: "WARN",
    Error: "ERROR"
};

const DateTypes = {
    Current: "CURRENT",
    Log: "LOG",
    Short: "SHORT",
    Long: "LONG"
};

const GetTypes = {
    Name: "NAME",
    Id: "ID",
    Tag: "TAG", 
    Query: "QUERY",
    QueryAll: "QUERYALL"
};

...
```

Comment: `LogTypes`, `DateTypes`, and `GetTypes` are declared in the same module you are using the `export`. Why are you using the `from` keyword as if you are getting them from somewhere else?

Comment: By the way, `export ... from ...;` is equivalent to `import ... from ...; export ...;`, and imports can only appear at the top of a module.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi just trying out anything I can. now I'm trying to import as module

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be a `<script>` tag for a module that is exporting things.

The script that **imports** those things needs a `<script type="module">` tag to load it.

It is the `import` statement causes the browser to request the URL for the module and load it, not a seperate `<script>` tag.

Comment: I've removed all the export statements, since I didn't really need them

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out when including JavaScript file and allowing the connection on CORS.

JS:

```
// log types
export const LogTypes = {
    Default: "DEFAULT",
    Info: "INFO",
    Warn: "WARN",
    Error: "ERROR"
};

// date types
export const DateTypes = {
    Current: "CURRENT",
    Log: "LOG",
    Short: "SHORT",
    Long: "LONG"
};

// supported types by the get function
export const GetTypes = {
    Name: "NAME",
    Id: "ID",
    Tag: "TAG", 
    Query: "QUERY",
    QueryAll: "QUERYALL"
};

// gets elements based on type and elm value
export const get = (type, elm) => {
    let result = null;

    switch (upper(type)) {
        case GetTypes.Name:
            result = document.getElementsByName(elm);
            break;

        case GetTypes.Id:
            result = document.getElementById(elm);
            break;

        case GetTypes.Tag:
            result = document.getElementsByTagName(elm);
            break;

        case GetTypes.Query:
            result = document.querySelector(elm).elements;
            break;

        case GetTypes.QueryAll:
            result = document.querySelectorAll(elm);
            break;

        default:
            throw new Error(type + " not supported");
    }

    return result;
};
```

HTML:

```
<script src="/SCRIPT/Creator.js"></script>
```

Comment: Figured out what?